# Remove focus when user presses ESC

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I'm using a `select2` dropbox. One odd thing I notice, if it's open and the user presses `ESC`, the dropbox closes but stays in focus?

Ho to change that, such that it closes and loses focus when pressing `ESC`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to **select2-close** event. When this event is fire you can remove "active" class.

```
$('.YOURCLASS').removeClass('select2-container-active');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6Lcy/7/)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mess with the controls behaviour you trust that the browser implementation got usability right.

This is the best advice to give, because based on platform (gnome/kde on linux, safari, mac, windows and so on) those rules may have slight differences. So best is, you don't be picky about how the default behaviour handles these cases and let it "do its thing", which is probably what users expect.

That said, what you can do to un-focus the drop-down list is one of these:

1) catch the ESC key and invoke blur() on the drop-down list;

-or-

2) catch the ESC key and invoke focus() on an element of your choice.